# SpringBoot White page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

I just start learning SpringBoot.

I use spring boot build-in tomcat get my spring boot program run. But when I try to visit the page, it gives me a *Whitelabel Error Page*.

When I start this program, it shows as follow:

[image]

I think my program and tomcat start successfully.

This is my start code:
**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

This is my Controller code:

**BookController.java**

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
    private IBookService bookService;

    public BookController(IBookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/book_list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllBook(Model model, HttpSession httpSession, HttpRequest httpRequest) throws Exception {
        List<Book> list = bookService.getAllBook();
        model.addAttribute("bookList", list);
        return "book";
    }
}
```

So if I visit '**localhost:8080/bookstore/book_list**', it will find the controller and this controller should help me go to the /WEB-INF/jsp/book.jsp because my WebMvcConfig like following:

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

But why this is a white page?

This is my program structure:

[image]

Comment: can you try adding @RequestMapping(value = "/bookstore") below your @Controller annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DemoApplication` is in a `demo` subpackage. The default is that it only scans subpackages of the class annotated with [`@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html), so it doesn't find any of your components.

Two ways to fix:

1. Move the class out of the `demo` package.

   This is what Spring Boot demo applications usually do.
2. Specify the packages to scan:

   ```java
   @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.zx")
   ```

   Alternatively, use [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html), same thing:

   ```java
   @SpringBootApplication
   @ComponentScan("com.zx")
   ```